# How can I get my character to aim correctly?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have a character that I am using the mouse to aim where he points his gun. Right now I kinda have him aiming but since he is not pointing his gun perfectly forward in the animation it doesn't look right.  Is there a way I can add on to the code below to rotate the spines so he aims forward perfectly? I cant seem to think of a way.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
    rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;


    rotationX = ClampAngle(rotationX, minX, maxX);
    rotationY = ClampAngle(rotationY, minY, maxY);



    Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
    Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-rotationY, Vector3.right);



    transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < spines.Length; counter++)
    {
        spines[counter].localRotation = originalSpineRotations[counter] * yQuaternion ;
    }
}
```

this is the part of the above code that does the aiming

```
    for (int counter = 0; counter < spines.Length; counter++)
    {
        spines[counter].localRotation = originalSpineRotations[counter] * yQuaternion ;
    }
```

[Looking Down](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48751132/lookingDown.png)
[Looking Up](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48751132/lookingUp.png)
[Direction Diagram](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48751132/diagram.png)

Comment: I would safe the rotation `transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion;` for the last, else you character will bank. So i think the 'problem' is not in the code you provided, but where you stack your rotations(matrices).

Comment: Nothing Changes when I put it last, and the problem is the animations witch I can not fix myself and I have noone to fix them so I was wondering if there is a way I can add into the code to fix the problem

Comment: Also, shouldn't the rotationY been divided by the number of spines? Or does the originalSpineRotations[counter] contains a fragment

Comment: I thought it would need to be divided by them to but I got weird results when I did that and they went away when i changed it to this

edit* the weird results when dividing was it was always resetting to the defalut position

Comment: Can you update an image so i can see the results? (i'm trying to imagen what you're creating) :)

Comment: Waiting for them to upload to dropbox to share so those will be posted soon

Comment: This looks like i said, the order of rotation, I don't think something is wrong with your calculation, but when you are drawing the meshes. First the 'yQuaternion' then the 'xQuaternion', Would you like to post the calculation of the matrices? There is a difference with like prepending/appending matrix calculations. If you look at another direction, does the banking gets worse of gets less? TTYL

Comment: it does it the same amount in any direction and if I comment all the xQuaternion stuff out it still does it

Comment: Just posted a diagram to what I think is causing the problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So after many hours of messing around with math and trying to get it to work I started to forget that Quaternion.AngleAxis needs a static direction like Vector3.right.  When I first did this I was useing Vector3.right but while trying to figure how to make it look right i started using gun.right witch changes so it was making weirder things happen.  When I finally thought about how quaternion.AngleAxis needed a static direction I created a empty GameObject and put it in the position and rotation of the gun and used that as the direction argument

```
Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-rotationY, axisObj.right);
```